# jQuery window 'hashchange' switch statement efficiency

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am showing items "selected" in a jQuery multiselect control based on values in the URL hash. For example,

```
http://localhost/index#options=2,3,4
```

renders items 2, 3, and 4 "selected" in the multiselect control based on a url hashQuery. My question is how to define the window "hashchange" event so that I do not have to account for every possible combination of values in order to determine what to show selected. For example, here is what I have started and what I would want to avoid because it is not efficient

```
 $(window).on('hashchange');
        if (hashQuery.option) {
            switch (hashQuery.option) {
                case '1':
                    $("#options option[value='1']").attr("selected", "selected");
                    break;
                case '1,2':
                    $("#options option[value='1']").attr("selected", "selected");
                    $("#options option[value='2']").attr("selected", "selected");
                    break;
                case '1,2,3':
                    $("#options  option[value='1']").attr("selected", "selected");
                    $("#options option[value='2']").attr("selected", "selected");
                    $("#options option[value='3']").attr("selected", "selected");
                    break;
                default:
                    //
            }
        }
```

How can this be made more efficient and still accomplish the same? Please let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a list of option values, so treat it like a list of option values.  Turn it into an array, then you can simply loop through the array and select the option for each value.

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
  var values = hashQuery.option.split(',');
  // values is now an array like ['1', '2', '3']

  // so just loop through it
  var selector;
  for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    selector = "#options option[value='"+ values[i] +"']";
    $(selector).attr('selected', 'selected');
  }
};
```

And this isn't about *efficiency* (how quickly your code executes).  In fact using a loop might make it very slightly slower.  It's about just having *clean code* that does the right thing when you add more options.